# "not declared in this scope" error message

Tags: arduino-uno

Error message `'dir1PinL' was not declared in this scope.` keeps coming up. Any ideas?

```cpp
#include "Arduino.h"

/*motor control*/
void go_Advance(void)  //Forward
{
  digitalWrite(dir1PinL, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(dir2PinL, LOW);
  digitalWrite(dir1PinR, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(dir2PinR, LOW);
}

void go_Left(void)  //Turn left
{
  digitalWrite(dir1PinL, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(dir2PinL, LOW);
  digitalWrite(dir1PinR, LOW);
  digitalWrite(dir2PinR, HIGH);
}

void go_Right(void)  //Turn right
{
  digitalWrite(dir1PinL, LOW);
  digitalWrite(dir2PinL, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(dir1PinR, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(dir2PinR, LOW);
}

void go_Back(void)  //Reverse
{
  digitalWrite(dir1PinL, LOW);
  digitalWrite(dir2PinL, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(dir1PinR, LOW);
  digitalWrite(dir2PinR, HIGH);
}

void stop_Stop()    //Stop
{
  digitalWrite(dir1PinL, LOW);
  digitalWrite(dir2PinL, LOW);
  digitalWrite(dir1PinR, LOW);
  digitalWrite(dir2PinR, LOW);
}

/*set motor speed */
void set_Motorspeed(int speed_L, int speed_R)
{
  analogWrite(speedPinL, speed_L);
  analogWrite(speedPinR, speed_R);
}

//Pins initialize
void init_GPIO()
{
  pinMode(dir1PinL, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dir2PinL, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(speedPinL, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(dir1PinR, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dir2PinR, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(speedPinR, OUTPUT);
  stop_Stop();
}

void setup()
{
  init_GPIO();
  go_Advance();//Forward
  set_Motorspeed(255, 255);
  delay(5000);

  go_Back();//Reverse
  set_Motorspeed(255, 255);
  delay(5000);

  go_Left();//Turn left
  set_Motorspeed(255, 255);
  delay(5000);

  go_Right();//Turn right
  set_Motorspeed(255, 255);
  delay(5000);

  stop_Stop();//Stop
}

void loop()
{
}
```

This is the entire error message:

```
Arduino: 1.8.6 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"

C:\Users\William\Documents\smartcar-lesson1\smartcar-lesson1.ino: In function 'void go_Advance()':

smartcar-lesson1:20:16: error: 'dir1PinL' was not declared in this scope

   digitalWrite(dir1PinL, HIGH);

                ^

smartcar-lesson1:21:16: error: 'dir2PinL' was not declared in this scope

   digitalWrite(dir2PinL,LOW);

                ^

smartcar-lesson1:22:16: error: 'dir1PinR' was not declared in this scope

   digitalWrite(dir1PinR,HIGH);

                ^

smartcar-lesson1:23:16: error: 'dir2PinR' was not declared in this scope

   digitalWrite(dir2PinR,LOW);

                ^

C:\Users\William\Documents\smartcar-lesson1\smartcar-lesson1.ino: In function 'void go_Left()':

smartcar-lesson1:27:16: error: 'dir1PinL' was not declared in this scope

   digitalWrite(dir1PinL, HIGH);

                ^

smartcar-lesson1:28:16: error: 'dir2PinL' was not declared in this scope

   digitalWrite(dir2PinL,LOW);

                ^

smartcar-lesson1:29:16: error: 'dir1PinR' was not declared in this scope

   digitalWrite(dir1PinR,LOW);

                ^

smartcar-lesson1:30:16: error: 'dir2PinR' was not declared in this scope

   digitalWrite(dir2PinR,HIGH);

                ^

C:\Users\William\Documents\smartcar-lesson1\smartcar-lesson1.ino: In function 'void go_Right()':

smartcar-lesson1:34:16: error: 'dir1PinL' was not declared in this scope

   digitalWrite(dir1PinL, LOW);

                ^

smartcar-lesson1:35:16: error: 'dir2PinL' was not declared in this scope

   digitalWrite(dir2PinL,HIGH);

                ^

smartcar-lesson1:36:16: error: 'dir1PinR' was not declared in this scope

   digitalWrite(dir1PinR,HIGH);

                ^

smartcar-lesson1:37:16: error: 'dir2PinR' was not declared in this scope

   digitalWrite(dir2PinR,LOW);

                ^

C:\Users\William\Documents\smartcar-lesson1\smartcar-lesson1.ino: In function 'void go_Back()':

smartcar-lesson1:41:16: error: 'dir1PinL' was not declared in this scope

   digitalWrite(dir1PinL, LOW);

                ^

smartcar-lesson1:42:16: error: 'dir2PinL' was not declared in this scope

   digitalWrite(dir2PinL,HIGH);

                ^

smartcar-lesson1:43:16: error: 'dir1PinR' was not declared in this scope

   digitalWrite(dir1PinR,LOW);

                ^

smartcar-lesson1:44:16: error: 'dir2PinR' was not declared in this scope

   digitalWrite(dir2PinR,HIGH);

                ^

C:\Users\William\Documents\smartcar-lesson1\smartcar-lesson1.ino: In function 'void stop_Stop()':

smartcar-lesson1:48:16: error: 'dir1PinL' was not declared in this scope

   digitalWrite(dir1PinL, LOW);

                ^

smartcar-lesson1:49:16: error: 'dir2PinL' was not declared in this scope

   digitalWrite(dir2PinL,LOW);

                ^

smartcar-lesson1:50:16: error: 'dir1PinR' was not declared in this scope

   digitalWrite(dir1PinR,LOW);

                ^

smartcar-lesson1:51:16: error: 'dir2PinR' was not declared in this scope

   digitalWrite(dir2PinR,LOW);

                ^

C:\Users\William\Documents\smartcar-lesson1\smartcar-lesson1.ino: In function 'void set_Motorspeed(int, int)':

smartcar-lesson1:57:15: error: 'speedPinL' was not declared in this scope

   analogWrite(speedPinL,speed_L); 

               ^

smartcar-lesson1:58:15: error: 'speedPinR' was not declared in this scope

   analogWrite(speedPinR,speed_R);   

               ^

C:\Users\William\Documents\smartcar-lesson1\smartcar-lesson1.ino: In function 'void init_GPIO()':

smartcar-lesson1:64:10: error: 'dir1PinL' was not declared in this scope

  pinMode(dir1PinL, OUTPUT); 

          ^

smartcar-lesson1:65:10: error: 'dir2PinL' was not declared in this scope

  pinMode(dir2PinL, OUTPUT); 

          ^

smartcar-lesson1:66:10: error: 'speedPinL' was not declared in this scope

  pinMode(speedPinL, OUTPUT);  

          ^

smartcar-lesson1:68:10: error: 'dir1PinR' was not declared in this scope

  pinMode(dir1PinR, OUTPUT);

          ^

smartcar-lesson1:69:11: error: 'dir2PinR' was not declared in this scope

   pinMode(dir2PinR, OUTPUT); 

           ^

smartcar-lesson1:70:11: error: 'speedPinR' was not declared in this scope

   pinMode(speedPinR, OUTPUT); 

           ^

exit status 1
'dir1PinL' was not declared in this scope

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

Comment: is that the whole error message?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like you've created any variable with that name in your code.  That's what that error message usually means.  You must create a variable and give it a value before you can use it elsewhere.  Go find any good C++ tutorial and go through the first bit of it and you will learn these sorts of basics pretty quick.

Your code would need a line at the top that looks something like:

```
int dir1PinL = 2
```

or whatever number value you want that variable to have depending on what pin you're actually talking about there.  Similar for the other variables you are trying to use.